# Dart flutter Admob not working in Ios. I release My app almost 1 week ago

Tags: ios, flutter, admob

My flutter app has AdMob.

In android, it works very well.
But in iOS, is not working.

Admob Test Id works in iOS but my real id not working.
I submit my app in the iOS review center and it confirmed. So, my app is on AppStore now.
But still, my real AdMob is not working, and AdMob can't find my app to connect.

I release my app one week ago.

Is anyone can help me?

Comment: for iOS has IDFA, you can check it.

Comment: You use the same app ID and AD ID for both iOS and android? Working on android but not on iOS?

Comment: No, I made admob for android and ios... And I use 'Platform.isAndroid' for android ID, 'Platform.isIos' for ios ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has solved by itself...
Today (after one week from I asked this issue) iOS Admob showing.
I didn't do anything to solve this problem.
I think it was just iOS and Admob problem..

Comment: One week later? I have this problem now, and I'm reading that after a few hours it starts showing... But weeks... it's too much.